# SSAS - Data Cube Hierarchy not visible in Excel

Tags: ssas, bids

Initial Request: Create hierarchies over customer names and product descriptions.

Problem:  I created several similar hierarchies and the product description hierarchy is not visible in Excel

Supporting details 
The computed columns for each hierarchy look like this:

Column Name: Product Description Prefix1
Expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN [ProductDescription] = 'N/A' THEN 'N/A'
ELSE LEFT([ProductDescription], 1) 
END
```

Column Name: Product Description Prefix5
Expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN [ProductDescription] = 'N/A' THEN 'N/A'
ELSE LEFT([ProductDescription], 5) 
END
```

Column Name: Product Description Prefix10
Expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN [ProductDescription] = 'N/A' THEN 'N/A'
ELSE LEFT([ProductDescription], 10) 
END
```

In my product dimension, I created a Product Description Hierarchy that is leveled

- Product Description Prefix1
- Product Description Prefix5
- Product Description Prefix10
- Product Description

With 1 being an attribute relationship to 5, 5 to 10, 10 to Product Description, and Product Description to the Key: Product.

Each one of these attributes have their KeyColumn collections are set:
Product Description Prefix1's KeyColumns: Being its self
Product Description Prefix5's KeyColumns: 1 and 5
Product Description Prefix10's KeyColumns: 1,5,10
Product Description's KeyColumns: 1,5,10, and Product Description

Right now, I'm choosing AttributeHierarchyVisible = False because I don't want the user to to be able to select the individual attribute.

Any help as to what I am missing causing the hierarchy to become visible would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this issue lies in the naming of the computed columns.

You have spaces in the names of the computed columns.

With the spaces, the data correctly deployed where it should have; however, Excel 2010 would not acknowledge the existence of a hierarchy -- even though the data was visible through management studio.  Strange.

Once the spaces are removed and the cube deployed, the hierarchy will be visible.

Comment: I recreated every part of my problem, but I didn't think that the spaces were the issue since the hierarchy made it to the cube database and just wasnt visible in excel.  Thank you!