# Dimensions Visible in SSAS Cube browser, but not in Excel

Tags: excel, ssas, excel-2010, ssas-2012

I have a cube in SSAS 2012, but only a subset of the dimensions are visible in Excel 2010.

I have seen this question:

[SSAS - Data Cube Hierarchy not visible in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365100/ssas-data-cube-hierarchy-not-visible-in-excel)

however, some of the 'missing' dimensions do not have spaces.  Additionally, a variant of the cube is deployed to a separate server, and has all of the dimensions visible (same software involved in both cases).  We cannot switch to using the alternate version on the other server due to some other differences (its under development).  The last change that was made was to update the credentials used when accessing the database.

Dimensions:

- Date
- Metrics
- Hospital Facilities

Dimension visible to Excel 2010:

- Metrics

What is the typical cause of this type of issue, and how can I correct this, so that all dimensions will be visible?

Comment: Do you use the same Windows user when accessing the cube from Management Studio and from Excel, or is the user accessing the cube from management Studio maybe a database administrator and the Excel user is not? Do you have any roles defined on your cube?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSAS project go to Tab 'Cube Structure', select Dimension which is not visible and in right corner on Dimension 'Properties' window set property 'Visible' to True.
It's very similar to this:

[Dimension properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174900.aspx)

[image]

There can be problem and with rigths... without screenshots, say something more is hard...